# Fetching a string of IDS in a Column using explode (Eloquent model Laravel)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

For the table Exam I have this:

--id----section_id

--1----- 2,3

when I use this in **Exam.php** Model:

```
public function Sections(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Section::class, 'section_id');
}
```

It only shows and take in consideration the section_id=2 but not both of the IDS.
How I can get Info from both Ids ?

in the ***blade.php*** :

```
  @foreach ($Exams as $exams)
             <tr>
                <td>{{$exams->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$exams->Sections}}</td>
            </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Have two entries in your table, `1---2` and `1---3`

Comment: Reconsider how you've defined the relationship. It is advisable to [not store data as a delimited list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574/281278).